# Sistema de agendamento de e-mails

Tags: php, mysql, email, envio-de-email

Tenho a seguinte problemática:

Um usuário realiza um etapa de um teste X, quando ele clica para obter o primeiro resultado preciso criar 9 mensagens de e-mail para serem enviadas ao logo de 3 dias, de manhã(7:00), tarde(13:00) e a noite(21:00). A dúvida é como posso definir os 3 horários? As datas já consegui.

Minha tabela de agendamento tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE maas_emails_agendados (
  email_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  email_destinatario_nome varchar(255) default NULL,
  email_destinatario varchar(255) default NULL,
  email_assunto varchar(255) default NULL,
  email_mensagem text,
  email_agendamento datetime default NULL,
  cliente_id int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (email_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Resumindo, poderia ser mais especifico, qual o real problema ? Você implementou algum código, se sim, posta ele.

Comment: Qual a dificuldade? Implementação ou lógica? Se forem horários fixos, só fazer um `for` nos dias e inserir em 3 horários.

Comment: Não exite uma forma melhor do que usar um `for` dentro de outro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No fim ficou assim, alguma sugestão de como simplificar?

```
$dias = 3;

$horarios = array(
    'Manhã'=>'7:00:00',
    'Tarde'=>'13:00:00',
    'Noite'=>'21:00:00'
);

for ($i=1; $i <= $dias; $i++) { 

   foreach ($horarios as $key => $value) {

       $email_destinatario = $cliente_email;

       $email_assunto = SISTEMA_NAME.': Autodiagnóstico '.$key.' - Dia #'.$i;

       $email_mensagem = $functions->get_emails_tags($dados_email['email_corpo'],$cliente_id);

       $data = date('Y-m-d '.$value);

       $email_agendamento = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+".$i." days",strtotime($data)));

       $dados_emails = array(
           'email_destinatario_nome'=>$cliente_nome,
           'email_destinatario'=>$email_destinatario,
           'email_assunto'=>$email_assunto,
           'email_mensagem'=>$email_mensagem,
           'email_agendamento'=>$email_agendamento,
           'cliente_id'=>$cliente_id
       );

       $conecta->inserir('maas_emails_agendados',$dados_emails);

    }

}
```

Comment: Bem, é isso ai... na minha visão é a melhor forma.